# ScalaTest console output in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm pretty frustrated with how to make IDEA output anything from the tests to console. I've tried different versions of Scala, ScalaTest and IDEA - nothing helps. Currently my setup is: scala-2.10.0-snapshot, scalatest_2.9.1-1.6.1, idea 110.3. The project is managed by maven. Could anyone please help? I'm expecting to see something like that: http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_feature_spec

Comment: I don't know about Maven, but ScalaTest works fine in conjunction with SBT, with output to the SBT console window in IDEA (using the SBT plugin). Are you using the Maven plugin?

Comment: Thanks. Since since version 11 Idea provides a decent support for FSC I stopped using SBT because it introduces several extra steps in workflow and I don't find its management approach any easier than Maven. Now I use Maven only and I run tests as usual Idea run configurations. Probably this issue is a bug of Idea's test runner adapter. Gonna post it on their tracker later

Comment: println() works here, with IDEA 10.5.2. What's idea 110.3?? And what on Earth is scala-10.0-snapshot? Is that scala-2.10.0-snapshot?

Comment: idea 110.3 is an EAP release (see  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP), about the scala version - you're right thanks for pointing this one out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem of Idea Scala plugin. Later builds start putting some output into the console, but not everything one should expect. For latest releases of the plugin check out http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Nika

Answer (score 1):

I've just been through the whole "getting punished by IDEA" thing and I have this solution for you...

Add [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html) and [slf4s](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s) to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.weiglewilczek.slf4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4s_${scala.version}</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.30</version>
</dependency>
```

NOTES:
I've used ${scala.version} in the slf4s artifactId - make sure you have this defined or replace it with 2.9.1 or something like that.
Also - you'll need the scala-tools repo available for dependencies too - which I'm assuming you'll have as I think you need it to compile.

Then add a file called logback.xml to your resources folder containing this:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date,%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS},%thread,%-5level,%logger{36},%line,%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

*My pattern there is potentially a bit weird - it's actually from a file appender that spits it out as a CSV I can open and graph in Excel easily.*

Then extend the trait Logging in your app like so:

```
import swing._
import com.weiglewilczek.slf4s.Logging

object App extends SwingApplication with Logging {

    override def startup(args: Array[String]) {

        logger.info("Starting init...")
    }
}
```

And the info message, "Starting init..." with a bunch of other stuff should appear in the console window.

Logback and slf4s are topics that I've linked to.

IMPORTANT AND AWESOME:

I can't remember what it's called but the logging methods you use to post messages all have signatures like info(message: => String) - as you can see in [logger.scala](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s/blob/master/src/main/scala/logger.scala).

This means the expression or block you pass to them will not get executed *at all* if the relevant level of logging isn't enabled in the config file.

So it only adds a method call and a flag-check to the code when it's turned off - which is pretty sweet imho  :)

Hope that helps,
Seth.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and nothing changed. Was there anything else you probably forgot to mention? Also I don't quite get how it is in any way related to `SwingApplication`.

Comment: I use the same technique for my tests as well - it solved the problem for me there too.

Comment: Hrmm - well this wasn't working for me previously and I thought I'd fixed it through logging but now System.out is working as well.  The only change I can think of is that I shifted my IDEA project out of my source control dir into a completely external location - I don't change any IDEA settings except font and code style and stuff.  Sorry that didn't work - do try disabling breakpoints and things like that - the "Any Exception" breakpoint in particular has been causing me many problems.